# wordpress last all added get meta value by post id

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, post-meta, meta-query

How to get the last added meta value by post id

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'picture_upload_1'
    );
    $dbResult = new WP_Query($args);

var_dump($dbResult);
```

but I am not receiving the meta value

Comment: you want only 'picture_upload_1' of all post_meta?

Comment: The last added value for a particular post, or all posts?

Answer (score -1):

Try this i have edited the rectified what you exactly looking for.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$dbResult = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $dbResult->have_posts() ) {
    $dbResult->the_post();
    global $post;

    // You can pass specific post id to get post meta values 
    $fields = get_post_custom_keys($post->ID);    // all keys for post as values of array
    if ($fields) {
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {

            // $value will give you meta_key's
            $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID,$value,true);

            // Exclude WP System Meta Keys
            if ($value[0] != '_') { 
                // Meta Value
                echo $meta_value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want all last added value not only one

Comment: What do you mean all Last added value?

Comment: if i update and there could be more than one entry in table at one time then i want all latest added meta value by post id

Comment: yes last added or all. explain clear

Comment: last added there can possibility that there could be more than one row at time

Comment: Have you tried above solution, did it worked for you?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I will added order by modified by date. Hope is work

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'modified',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => 'picture_upload_1'
    );
```

Comment: This is returning the latest post with that meta value. Dhara is asking for the last added *meta value*, not the last added *post*.

Comment: yes and i don't want single row i want all value which is last added